Can't set html for onchange for input
I am creating inputs in a table via a loop.
First I create a new cell
var nestedCell = newRow.insertCell(columncounter);
Then I create a new input, each input has a unique ID.
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.id = thisInputID;
input.value = value;

Then I try to insert an "onchange" function to that input
input.onchange =  function() { 
   alert(thisInputID);
}

The onchange function is fired, but because the value of thisInputID changes on every iteration only the last "thisInputID " is displayed instead of the id for that particular input. This is a problem. How do I assign an onchange function to each input which will pass a unique identifier for that input?
Here is the code all in one block:
                        var nestedCell = newRow.insertCell(columncounter);

                        let input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.type = 'text';
                        input.id = thisInputID;
                        input.value = value;
                        input.onchange =  function() { 
                            alert(thisInputID);
                        }

                        nestedCell.appendChild(input);

Edit: You have already given me a working answer :) but here is a jsfiddle showing the issue https://jsfiddle.net/carlschwarz/2bw1dm8k/1/
Edit #2 The ID is how to reference the value in the original JSON. On edit I can then use [0].price to update the original price in the JSON with the new value.

You did not post enough code to make this really clear, but the declaration of thisInputID is probably the key to the issue here. How and where is it declared? Is there some kind of loop involved? What does that look like?

To cut to the chase: you should be declaring variables with let or const, not var.

@Pointy I'm guessing that's "pseudo"-code and OP wants to retrieve the actual ID of the input which triggered the onchange

@DarkBee no, the OP clearly is using something that generates ID values, and then in the code posted at the top of the question, the generated ID is used to construct a new input element.\

That's actually true - Your suggestion should work as well then, but David pointed out in an answer what I was thinking/referring to

Ask yourself why you need IDs in the first place. For new programmers, IDs make it super easy to access elements, but as you get more experienced and build more complex applications, you realize how IDs make your code very brittle and harder to scale. There are plenty of other ways to reference elements than with static IDs.

The ID is how to reference the value in the original JSON. On edit I can then use [0].price to update the original price in the JSON with the new value.

If it just needs to alert its own id then you can access that directly:
input.onchange = function() { 
  alert(this.id);
}



Please generate valid HTML
Please use delegated event handlers - input works better than change
Please do not use innerHTML since it is vulnerable to XSS

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bv4hxgce/


const addData = (jsonInput, tablename, nestID) => {
  const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonInput);
  const table = document.querySelector(`#${tablename}`);

  // Ensure thead and tbody elements exist
  const thead = table.querySelector('thead') || table.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
  const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));

  // Create and populate header row in thead
  const headerRow = thead.insertRow(-1); // Insert row in thead
  const headers = Object.keys(jsonObject[0]);
  headers.forEach(header => {
    const cell = headerRow.insertCell();
    cell.innerText = header;
  });

  // Populate the data rows in tbody
  jsonObject.forEach((item, index) => {
    const dataRow = tbody.insertRow(-1);
    headers.forEach(header => {
      const cell = dataRow.insertCell();
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'text';
      input.value = item[header];
      input.id = `${nestID}[${index}].${header}`;
      cell.appendChild(input);
    });
  });

  // Event delegation for input onchange
  tbody.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      console.log(target.id); // Changed from alert to console.log for better UX in examples
    }
  });
};

let jsonInput = '[{"id":167915,"type":"variation","date_created":"2024-04-18T12:09:44"},{"id":167916,"type":"variation","date_created":"2024-04-18T12:09:44"},{"id":167917,"type":"variation","date_created":"2024-04-18T12:09:44"}]';
addData(jsonInput, "outputTable", "");
.as-console-wrapper { height: 60px; }
<table id="outputTable"></table>




You can assign an event callback function like this:
input.onchange = onChange;

For example, this is how you can use the event to grab the information about the input:
function onChange(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  console.log(`UPDATE ${input.id} = ${input.value}`);
}

Here is a small example of a spreadsheet-like application that tracks changes.


initSpreadsheet(document.getElementById('myTable'), 5, 5);

function initSpreadsheet(table, rows, columns) {
  let thead = table.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
  let tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  if (!thead) table.append(thead = document.createElement('thead'));
  if (!tbody) table.append(tbody = document.createElement('tbody'));

  const headerRow = thead.insertRow(0);
  const topLeft = headerRow.insertCell(0);
  topLeft.outerHTML = '<th></th>';
  for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    const headerCell = headerRow.insertCell(c + 1);
    headerCell.outerHTML = `<th>${indexToColumn(c + 1)}</th>`;
  }

  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    const currentRow = tbody.insertRow(r);
    const rowIdentifier = currentRow.insertCell(0);
    rowIdentifier.outerHTML = `<th>${r + 1}</th>`;
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      const cell = currentRow.insertCell(c + 1);
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'text';
      input.id = `${indexToColumn(c + 1)}${r + 1}`;
      input.onchange = onChange;
      cell.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
}

function onChange(event) {
  const input = event.target;
  console.log(`UPDATE ${input.id} = ${input.value}`);
}

function indexToColumn(index) {
  if (index <= 0) throw new Error("Index must be a positive integer.");
  index -= 1; // Adjust index for zero-based calculation
  const letter = String.fromCharCode(index % 26 + 'A'.charCodeAt(0));
  return index < 26 ? letter : indexToColumn(Math.floor(index / 26)) + letter
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 3rem !important;
}

/* Spreadsheet layout */
.speadsheet {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.speadsheet,
.speadsheet th,
.speadsheet td,
.speadsheet input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.speadsheet th {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.25rem;
}
.speadsheet td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.speadsheet td input {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: none;
}

/* Spreadsheet theme */
.speadsheet,
.speadsheet th,
.speadsheet td {
  border: thin solid #CCC;
}
.speadsheet th {
  background: #DDD;
}
.speadsheet tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #EEE;
}
.speadsheet td input {
  background: transparent;
}
<table id="myTable" class="speadsheet"></table>




Besides you could use this.id inside the onchange I would suggest a similar approach that does not uses invalid IDs, uses proper name="" attributes etc:


const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const addData = (jsonInput, tablename) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonInput);
  const elTable = el(tablename);

  // THEAD
  const elThead = elNew("thead");
  const elTr = elNew("tr");
  const elsTh = Object.keys(data?.[0]).map((k) => elNew("th", { textContent: k }));
  elTr.append(...elsTh);
  elThead.append(elTr);
  elTable.append(elThead);
  
  // TBODY
  const elTbody = elNew("tbody");
  data.forEach((item, rowIndex) => {
    const elTr = elNew("tr");
    const elsTd = Object.entries(item).map(([k, v]) => {
      const elTd = elNew("td");
      const elInput = elNew("input", {
        name: `${k}[${rowIndex}]`, // i.e: "id[0]" 
        type: "text",
        value: v,
        oninput() {
          console.log(`Row index: ${rowIndex}\nInput name: ${k}[${rowIndex}]\nInput value: ${elInput.value}`)
        }
      });
      elTd.append(elInput);
      return elTd;
    });
    elTr.append(...elsTd);
    elTbody.append(elTr);
  });
  elTable.append(elTbody);
};


// Usage:
const jsonInput = `[{"id":167915, "type":"variation", "date_created":"2024-04-18T12:09:44"},{"id":167916, "type":"something", "date_created":"2024-06-02T12:15:51"}]`;
addData(jsonInput, "#outputTable", "");
<table id="outputTable"></table>




variables inside for loops declared with var have function scope. You can use block level scoped declerations, const/let, listen to others as they pointed out the solution, or do this ugly thing that traps the variable:
input.onchange =  ((id) => function() { 
  alert(id);
})(thisInputID)

